# Advice on Optimizing Joins Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables : `videos`, `categories`, `video_categories`.

In `videos`, I have id, title, and other fields.
In `categories`, I have id and name.
In `video_categories`, I have id, video_id, and category_id.

One video can have multiple categories. So the video_categories table will be something like this.

```
id   video_id  category_id
1    1         1
2    1         2
3    1         3
```

If I want to have a list of videos and display their categories, which would be preferred?

1. Via PHP, call 1 query to get all videos, then loop on that to query to get each video's categories, and another query to get the category name. This will be really slow if the table is huge, right?
2. Via MySQL joins (need help on this). If I left join videos to video_categories, there will be 3 results of the same video_id. I can use GROUP BY or SELECT DISTINCT to get unique result, but how can I now get the categories' names?

My expected result will be something like this:

```
id title    categories
1  Video1   pop, rock, jazz
```

Comment: I don't think your question has to do with denormalization, per se. Your schema, as you describe it, is completely normalized, meaning it has no redundant data. You could denormalize it by adding the `categories` column to the `videos` table, in which you would store the comma spearated string of the category names (e.g. 'pop, rock, jazz') and then keep it in sync with the redundant data in the `categories` and `video_categories` tables. As it stands, your question is really just asking about optimizing your join technique, which can be done with the `group_concat` method, as others note.

Comment: yeah, I got confused. I must have thought denormalization as the reverse process of normalization, which is reading and displaying the normalized schema. I've edited the title to avoid confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For option 2, use `GROUP_CONCAT`. It will be ok

```
SELECT v.id, v.title, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name)
FROM videos v
INNER JOIN video_categories vc ON vc.video_id = v.id
INNER JOIN categories c ON vc.category_id = c.id
GROUP BY v.id, v.title
```

For `Group_Concat()` function `,` is the default separator. That's why I don't use it here.

Comment: never knew of GROUP_CONCAT. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. The same thing happened to me when I first heard about this function. Really helpful function.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT will cut you off after a few too many results being grouped together. I don't see it happening for you here, but I've had it stop concatenation after about the 200th grouped result.

Comment: @PatrickM: You can increase the length of `group_concat` by `SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 3):

Guessing the names of your other columns..

```
SELECT v.video_id, v.title, GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM videos v
LEFT JOIN video_categories vc ON vc.video_id = v.video_id
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.category_id = vc.category_id
GROUP BY v.video_id, v.title
```

Comment: Minor thing - it's SEPARATOR, and there shouldn't be a comma before `SEPARATOR`: `GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_name SEPARATOR ', ')`.

Comment: @EdGibbs Thanks, was typing off memory.

Comment: @MachoPaay the select and join and group is normal CI active record. For the group concat one, `$this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(c.name SEPARATOR ", ") as categories', false);` . c is the alias of my category table